# Binding html content using innerHTML click event is not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic2, ionic3

In .html

```
<ion-content padding><div [innerHTML]=divcontent></div></ion-content>
```

In .ts page

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
   this.divcontent = "<button ion-button (click)='btnClick()'>My Button</button>";// here i may get any html/ionic content
}
```

It is displaying "*My button*", but style is not getting applied nor the click event is working.

I read events are not supported if binding through innerHTML, is there any workaround to make it work?

Comment: why do you want to insert button as innerHTML? if you want to use different buttons at different scenio, use Angular If condiotion.

Comment: I would be using `*ngIf` here I think based on how it appears you are using it.

Comment: hi, you are telling to hide/show content based on condition, but my requirement is not to hide/show, i'l be getting html content (where i have written button tag) i need to bind it.
html content can be any thing.

Answer (score 0):

Could you refactor to use ngIf?

### page.html

```
<ion-content padding>
    <button ion-button *ngIf="showButton" (click)="btnClick()">My Button</button>
</ion-content>
```

### page.ts

```
showButton: boolean;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
   this.showButton = true;
}
```

Comment: hi, you are telling to hide/show content based on condition, but my requirement is not to hide/show, i'l be getting html content (where i have written button tag) i need to bind it.
html content can be any thing.

Comment: I see.  Was confused because you hard-coded the div.  You should probably update your question to say what sort of html you will be receiving from your server. I would try to prefer [Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) instead of innerHtml.  I have noticed that when components are added to ionic sometimes the css classes have "reflect" or something in the name and do not inherit properties from regular ones.  You should not display "anything".

Comment: hi @Philip Brack, please go through this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201662/compilemoduleandallcomponentsasync-is-taking-more-time-to-return-compiled-data

im able to compile but its taking more time in compile an bind